# Loading redux in angular 2, systemjs

Tags: javascript, angular

I m studying angular 2 and I wanted to use redux with it.

Actually, I've created my project using angular-cli on rc2 release.

I m having this systemjs configuration :

```
 /***********************************************************************************************
 * User Configuration.
 **********************************************************************************************/
/** Map relative paths to URLs. */
const map: any = {
};

/** User packages configuration. */
const packages: any = {
};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/***********************************************************************************************
 * Everything underneath this line is managed by the CLI.
 **********************************************************************************************/
const barrels: string[] = [
  // Angular specific barrels.
  '@angular/core',
  '@angular/common',
  '@angular/compiler',
  '@angular/http',
  '@angular/router',
  '@angular/platform-browser',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',

  // Thirdparty barrels.

  // App specific barrels.
  'app',
  'app/shared'
  /** @cli-barrel */
];

const cliSystemConfigPackages: any = {};
barrels.forEach((barrelName: string) => {
  cliSystemConfigPackages[barrelName] = { main: 'index' };
});

/** Type declaration for ambient System. */
declare var System: any;

// Apply the CLI SystemJS configuration.
System.config({
  map: {
    '@angular': 'vendor/@angular',
    'rxjs': 'vendor/rxjs',
    'main': 'main.js',
    'redux': 'vendor/redux/dist/redux.js',
  },
  packages: cliSystemConfigPackages
});

// Apply the user's configuration.
System.config({ map, packages });
```

And in my angular-cli.build.js :

```
/* global require, module */

var Angular2App = require('angular-cli/lib/broccoli/angular2-app');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  return new Angular2App(defaults, {
    vendorNpmFiles: [
      'redux/dist/redux.js',
      'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
      'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
      'zone.js/dist/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      'es6-shim/es6-shim.js',
      'reflect-metadata/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      'rxjs/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      '@angular/**/*.+(js|js.map)'
    ]
  });
};
```

The fact is that I m having this error in the web console :

[image]

What should I change to make redux available inside of my angular 2 app ? I m pretty sure this is a systemjs error and I don't know how to process...

Thanks for your help

Comment: Try to add map `'redux' : 'node_modules/redux'`.

Comment: In the `map` bit in your system-config.ts, there's a trailing comma after the redux line that shouldn't be there. It sounds silly, but remove that and see if it's resolved properly?

Comment: Didnt changed anything but thanks for this :)

Answer (score 0):

The configuration in [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/957#issuecomment-223329091) comment solved the Redux problem for me.